# Form of the fractional Laplacian in polar coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, fractional-calculus

Can anybody point out the form of the  fractional Laplacian
$ (-\Delta)^s f (\rho, \varphi) $ in polar co-ordinates on a restricted domain?
I am trying to solve an equation defined in a semi-unbounded interval $ I \subset \mathcal{R}$ with a boundary condition on the left e.g.
$ f(\rho=a, \varphi) $ and $f^\prime (\rho=a, \varphi) $.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Fractional laplacian is a nonlocal operator, so defining it on restricted area can be tricky or even impossible.

Comment: The domain is from R to infinity.